# Extraneous solutions from equation of motions

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, velocity, projectile

Suppose upwards vector is positive and downwards vector is negative.

**A ball is released from a tower of height $100 \, \rm m$ ($g=10 \, \rm m/s^2$). Find its final velocity**

Using the equation of motion $v^2=u^2+2as$, $v^2=\left(0^2+2\times(-10) \times(-100)\right) \rm m^2/s^2$ or $v^2=2000 \, \rm m^2/s^2$, which means $v=\pm\sqrt{2000} \, {\rm m/s}=\pm20\sqrt{5} \, {\rm m/s}$.

Now it is pretty obvious that $v=-20\sqrt{5} \, \rm m/s$, but why do we get the extraneous solution? What does it actually mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at how the equation is derived, it will help.

For simplicity, let's forget about the initial velocity, u, as it is zero.

The velocity after time t is:

v = at  (-10t in this case)

There is a linear increase in velocity from 0 to at (constant acceleration), so the average velocity during this time is 0.5at and therefore the distance travelled in time t is:

s = 0.5at*t

This gives us a t squared term, which would give us a v squared term if we substitute for t in our original equation v=at.
(After substitution, it gives us v²=2as).

So, think about the t squared term.  We get the same value if t is positive or negative.  So, what does negative t mean?  Well, minus 10 seconds means 10 seconds before the ball is released.

But the simple equation of motion does not account for the holding and releasing of the ball - it describes a continuous motion under constant acceleration, not necessarily starting at the point where the ball is at zero velocity at the top of the tower.   In this continuous motion, negative time is when the ball would be moving upwards (for example, having been thrown upwards) towards the top of the tower, decelerating so that it has zero velocity when it reaches the top of the tower.  **So this upwards (positive) velocity is the other solution to the equation.**